# Find default email client

Tags: c#, .net, email, email-client

Using C#, how can I determine which program is registered as the default email client? I don't need to launch the app, I just want to know what it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the Registry class to search the registry.  This console app demonstrates the principle.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace RegistryTestApp
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         object mailClient = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail", "", "none"); 
         Console.WriteLine(mailClient.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The default e-mail client is a per user policy. I agree with William Parke's response below.

Comment: Is there anyway how to launch the app?

Answer (score 8):

You can look in the registry on the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read this registry key from

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail
```

Answer (score 3):

Default email client depends on the user. `HKLM` lists all registered email clients; the first one returned may not be the current user's default. Better to read `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\Mail`.

Also this only gives you the name of the email application. If you want its executable file name, you have to go on with something like:

```
object mailCommand = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\" + mailClient.ToString() + @"\shell\open\command", "", "none");
```

and then remove anything extraneous from the command-line string that you don't need (quotes, parameters).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to find that info in the registry at `HKLM\Software\Clients\Mail`.

Look for the default string value.