# How do you determine what the default outgoing mail handler is?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, email

How can I find what the default mail handler is in Windows 7?

Purpose: When you send one or more .jpg files as email attachments using an application (or Windows Explorer), Windows Live Mail 2011 converts these attachments to "photo mail" and cloud storage. I consider this behavior quite rude, and would like to work around it by attaching a text file along with the .jpg files. I actually need to know *whether* the default mail handler is Windows Live Mail 2011. That way I don't have to send the additional text file out to users with other email applications.

Comment: Have you found [How and where exactly does the default email client gets set in the registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940358/how-and-where-exactly-does-the-default-email-client-gets-set-in-the-registry)? Note that the current version of Windows Live Mail on Windows 7 is Windows Live Mail 2012, in case you weren't aware of that.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton -- that's works. Write it up as an answer and I'll give you credit. (Windows Live Mail 2012 is advertised as Windows Live Mail 2011... weird. They both suffer from this affliction.)

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth writing it as an answer as the question is, in essence, pretty much a duplicate of the one I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the default email client, check the registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\Mail`. If there's not one there, check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mail`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set/change/view default programs, go to Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Default Programs>Set Default Programs.

Comment: I need to do this inside an application.