# How do I set standard email client in Windows 7 using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, email-client

I would like to set the standard email client in Windows 7 from .NET code, how do I do it?

Comment: setting the default email client is most likely a feature of the operating system that .NET has no access to

Comment: I am not going to make this an answer since I am not sure, but you may want to look into altering Registry variables for this.

Comment: [Registering an Application for Use with Default Programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#registration)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, +1, good reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default email program with the following Registry Key. Find it's content and mess with it:

Check the following link here at SO:

[Find default email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119745/find-the-default-email-client/1119872#1119872)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace RegistryTestApp
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         object mailClient = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail", "", "none"); 
         Console.WriteLine(mailClient.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1119872/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1119872/674700) Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V. Have you even tried it?

Comment: I have checked the registry key exist and its content. And the registry key class is not a mistery @AlexFilipovici. I forgot to link the post, but I'm doing it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to edit the following registry value. You would do something like the following with the Registry.SetValue Method.

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command", "", "\"C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office14\\OUTLOOK.EXE\" -c IPM.Note /m \"%1\"");
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy.aspx

Comment: Thank you dkroy, that works like a charm (on computers without Outlook)

Comment: @user2334811 glad I could help, if that is what you needed then I would appreciate it if you could accept my answer.